# How can I differentiate two POST requests in Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, api, http

I have a Node.JS server to connect an Android app to a SQL Server database. It already has a function to perform when a POST request is received. But now I want to add a login page to my app, and it will send a POST request with username and password. But how can I differentiate when it's a POST request to login and when it's a POST request to perform the other function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are using Node with HTTP library , you can use url node module to get the url path name  i.e.

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  var page = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
  console.log(page);
  res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
  if (page == "/") {
    res.write(`You are at home ${req.method}`);
  } else if (page == "/users") {
    res.write("/users api end point");
  } else if (page == "/login") {
    res.write("/login api end point");
  }
  res.end();
});
server.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have separate routes, one for each case.

Since you're using the Node.js HTTP Module you could do:

```
const http = require('http')
const url = require('url')

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' })

  // Only allow POST
  if (req.method !== 'POST') res.end('Wrong Method.')

  // Get url path
  const path = url.parse(req.url).pathname

  if (path === '/login') {
    let body = ''
    req.on('data', rawData => {
      body += rawData
    })

    req.on('end', () => {
      const user = JSON.parse(body)
      /* Do login here */
      res.end(`Login in ${user.username}`)
    })
  } else if (path === '/data') {
    let body = ''
    req.on('data', rawData => {
      body += rawData
    })

    req.on('end', () => {
      const data = JSON.parse(body)
      /* Do db stuff here */
      res.end(`Adding ${data.title} to database`)
    })
  } else {
    res.statusCode = 404
    res.end('Wrong Endpoint.')
  }
})

server.listen(8080)
```

This assumes you're sending your data as JSON. If you send it from a html form as form data (a login form for example) you should checkout this npm library to parse your incoming data:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/body

Learn more about

- How to create a http server: https://nodejs.org/es/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/
- request.url: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_url

Comment: I use Node.JS with HTTP library, how can I do it using it?

Comment: @EmilioSanches I changed my answer to an example with the http module.